# Filtering Shiny DataTable on column with cells that have multiple values

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I would like the `selectInput` field to include rows that have more than one `First_Ascent_Country` provided. The rows that have multiple country names in a single cell are separated by commas. I am interested in using `dplyr`, but am open to any solution that works!

For example, if someone chose the `UK` in the `First Ascent Country:` list input field, the resulting subset should include:

1. Ama Dablam since the `first_ascent_country` includes New Zealand, USA, and UK.
2. Amphu Gyabjen since the `first_ascent_country` includes just UK.

**Sample Data**:

```
peaks_stackoverflow <- structure(list(peak_id = c("AMAD", "AMPG", "ANN1", "ANN2", "ANN3", 
"ANN4"), peak_name = c("Ama Dablam", "Amphu Gyabjen", "Annapurna I", 
"Annapurna II", "Annapurna III", "Annapurna IV"), peak_alternative_name = c("Amai Dablang", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), height_metres = c(6814, 5630, 8091, 7937, 
7555, 7525), climbing_status = c("Climbed", "Climbed", "Climbed", 
"Climbed", "Climbed", "Climbed"), first_ascent_year = c(1961, 
1953, 1950, 1960, 1961, 1955), first_ascent_country = c("New Zealand, USA, UK", 
"UK", "France", "UK, Nepal", "India", "W Germany"), first_ascent_expedition_id = c("AMAD61101", 
"AMPG53101", "ANN150101", "ANN260101", "ANN361101", "ANN455101"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), spec = structure(list(cols = list(peak_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), peak_name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), peak_alternative_name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), height_metres = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), climbing_status = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), first_ascent_year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), first_ascent_country = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), first_ascent_expedition_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

**Shiny Code**:

```
country_names <- c("New Zealand", "USA", "UK", NA, "France", "Nepal",
"India", "W Germany", "Spain", "Japan", "Slovenia", "Austria", 
"Switzerland", "Norway", "Romania", "US", "Canada", "S Korea", 
"Netherlands", "Germany", "Poland", "Inida", "Argentina", 
"Yugoslavia", "Russia", "Ukraine", "Denmark", "Swiss", "Australia", 
"China", "Taiwan", "Singapore", "Italy", "Ireland", "Belgium", 
"Brazil", "Netherands", "Georgia", "Portugal")

library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Himalayan Climbing Expeditions - Peaks"),
    
    fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),
    
        fluidRow(
            column(4,
                   selectInput("first" ,
                               label = "First Ascent Country:",
                               choices = c("All", country_names),
                               selected = "All",
                               multiple = TRUE)))
                                        
            ),

        DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Filter data based on selections
    output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable({
        data <- peaks_stackoverflow
        
        if (input$first != "All") {
            data <- data[data$first_ascent_country == input$first,]
        }
        data
    }
    ))
    
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `stringr` you can use `str_detect` to identify any matches for country with your `input$first` vector. Using `str_c` you can join all your `input$first` strings together into a single string search pattern.

Since you use `multiple = TRUE`, it is unclear what results you might want if "All" is included with additional specific countries added. One possibility: if you check if `any` of the selections with your input are not "All", you can subset further.

```
library(stringr) 

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable({
    req(input$first)
    data <- peaks_stackoverflow
    if (any(input$first != "All")) {
      data <- data %>%
        dplyr::filter(str_detect(first_ascent_country, 
                                 str_c(input$first, collapse = '|')))
    }
    data
  }))
  
}
```

Alternatively, with base R you can subset and match strings using `grepl`:

```
data <- subset(data, grepl(paste0(input$first, collapse = '|'), first_ascent_country))
```

Finally, you can create an alphabetized list of countries from your data (in case this might be needed or considered):

```
country_names <- sort(
  unique(trimws(unlist(strsplit(peaks_stackoverflow$first_ascent_country, ','))))
)
```